# Encrypt User's email address

Tags: php, symfony, security, doctrine, swiftmailer

I'm trying to encrypt a User's email address, do you have any ideas to do it in a clean way?

For the rest of the fields I use `michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle`. It is a doctrine extension. When I tried to use it on the email field: swiftmailer's Validator (or even symfony mailer) throws an exception `Address in mailbox given [..., ...] does not comply with RFC 2822`

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @Encrypted
 * @Assert\NotBlank( message="L'email est nécessaire pour l'inscription à nos services")
 * @Assert\Email( message="Adresse e-mail invalide")
 */
 private $email;
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the email address? Remember that if you encrypt it you will need to decrypt it before you and use it to send email.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, project specs request that the values in the db be encrypted, and yes I realized that I have to decrypt it everywhere I use it. so i'm asking if there's a way to decrypt immediatly after sql queries

Comment: Perhaps you need [MySQL Enterprise Encryption](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/encryption.html)

Comment: "project specs request that the values in the db be encrypted" -> A better approach would be to encrypt the whole database. This is particularly easy if you use something like AWS RDS. It should be possible with plain MySQL too: https://serverfault.com/questions/538715/whats-a-good-way-to-encrypt-a-mysql-database-and-is-it-worth-it

Comment: If I couldn't encrypt the whole database (database-side) I would probably use a custom doctrine type. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html however, the library you're using *seems* to already do everything you need, so the question is, why doesn't it decrypt ... or maybe there's actually something else wrong...

Comment: Try to create two properties, one called `rawEmail`, and second `email`. Only the encrypted one is annotate with Doctrine and put in database. And use rawEmail with openssl_encrypt functions to encrypt and decrypt.